# Does Cassandra have roles or services like Hadoop?

Tags: cassandra

Does Cassandra have roles or services like Hadoop? More specifically, the options we see in nodetool, binary, thrift, gossip etc. should they be called as roles or services?

Answer (score 2):

All nodes in C* share the same 'role' which is that of a C* node. The things you have listed could be thought of as services but they are almost always necessary to run C*.

#### Interfaces to the C* system

- thrift (old C* drivers soon to be deprecated and removed)
- binary (new C* drivers)

These are different ways a client can communicate with C*.

#### Intra C* state communication

- gossip

If gossip is off there is no communication about the current state of the cluster.

---

In a normal C* situation all of these should be on, maybe you would turn off thrift if you aren't using older drivers.